# IOS equalization to onConsoleMessage in Android

Tags: android, ios, uiwebview, android-webview

I Android there I can extend `WebChromeClient` and override `onConsoleMessage` to monitor WebView console messages
.

```
 private class ChromeClient extends WebChromeClient{
        @Override
        public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage consoleMessage) {
            String msg = String.format("%s at line %s, scourceID: %s, level: %s", consoleMessage.message(),
                    consoleMessage.lineNumber(), consoleMessage.sourceId(), consoleMessage.messageLevel());
            Log.d("Console", msg);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

How can I implement that in IOS with `UIWebView`?

Comment: what you mean by monitoring webview console messages?

Comment: I wont to see them in xcode console

Answer (score 0):

something like:

```
NSString *message=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",messageString];
NSLog(@"console==>%@",message);
```

Comment: Where I catch the javascript console messages?

Comment: then try first on browser and then only use that page with ios webview...webview only has method to print error message.